# How to get fractions in an integer division?

Tags: c, integer-division

How do you divide two integers and get a double or float answer in C?

Comment: "decimal" is a representation (as "hexadecimal", "octal", "binary") which applies to integer or non-integer numbers. You mean, I guess, "get a non-integer result".

Comment: This is how you get fractions (rational numbers) with integer division `printf("%d %d/%d" x/y, x%y, y);`. Are you sure you don't want a non-integer result?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to cast one or the other to a `float` or `double`.

```
int x = 1;
int y = 3;

// Before
x / y; // (0!)

// After
((double)x) / y; // (0.33333...)
x / ((double)y); // (0.33333...)
```

Of course, make sure that you are store the *result* of the division in a `double` or `float`!  It doesn't do you any good if you store the result in another `int`.

---

Regarding @Chad's comment ("`[tailsPerField setIntValue:tailsPer]`"):

Don't pass a double or float to [`setIntValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setIntValue:) when you have [`setDoubleValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setDoubleValue:), etc. available.  That's probably the same issue as I mentioned in the comment, where you aren't using an explicit cast, and you're getting an invalid value because a double is being read as an int.

For example, on my system, the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double x = 3.14;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
1374389535
```

because the double was attempted to be read as an int.

Comment: Right. Convert the integers before you perform the division.

Comment: double tp;
double x;
x = tn; //(tn is a int) normally  10
tp = x/fn; // fn is also a int (normally 5) but i still get 0

Comment: @Chad: The code looks right.  How have you determined that the result is zero?  Are you doing something like `printf("%d", tp)`?  That tries to print the content of a double as an int, and you won't get the correct results.  Your compiler should have warned you if you did that.  For a double the format string is `%lf`.

Comment: its actually being sent to a gui... 

tailsPer = tailsNum / ((double)curNum); //tailsper is a double
[tailsPerField setIntValue:tailsPer];

// this is in cocoa

Answer (score 4):

Use type-casting.
For example,

```
main()
    {
        float a;
        int b = 2, c = 3;
        a = (float) b / (float) c;     // This is type-casting
        printf("%f", a);
    }
```