# Taylor expansion of function, f(x)=sin(x)+cos(x) in C programming has an output error. Any suggestions?

Tags: c, math, taylor-series

I'm new to programming. My uni course has a programming module included (C) and i need some help figuring what has happened to my code.

For sin(x) I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/*Taylor series expansion of sin(x)*/
int main(void)
{
    float x, ans;
    int i, fac, n, sign;

    printf("Value for x: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("Value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=1, fac=1, ans=x, sign=-1; i<=n; i++)
        {
        fac*=(2*i+1)*2*i;
        ans+=sign*pow(x,2*i+1)/fac;
        sign*=-1;
        }

    printf("Answer is %f.\n", ans); /*Taylor expansion completed*/

    return 0;
}
```

I've now (with help) fixed expansion for sin(x). But for the full question I am having difficulty getting right.

So far my expansion for f(x)=sin(x)+cos(x) looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x, sin, cos;
    float i, j, fac1, fac2, n, sign, ans;

    printf("Value for x: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("Value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=1, fac1=1, fac2=1, sin=x, cos=1, ans=1+x, sign; i<=n; i++)
    {
        fac1*=(2*i+1)*2*i; /*factorial expansion for sin(x)*/
        fac2*=2*i*(2*i-1); /*factorial expansion for cos(x)*/
        sin+=sign*pow(x,2*i+1)/fac1; /*Series expansion of sin(x)*/
        cos+=sign*pow(x,2*i)/fac2; /*Series expansion of cos(x)*/
        sign*=-1;
        ans=sin+cos; /*Final step*/
    }

    printf("Answer is %f.\n", ans); /*Taylor expansion completed*/

    return 0;
}
```

I assumed this would work, but for example plugging in 1 an 10 gives 1065353216 (basically grossly wrong). Any suggestions with this one?

Comment: You must always check the return value of `scanf`; You don't know if it fails or not.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? when you typ in 5 and 5?

Comment: How do i do that if I'm using Microsoft Visual Studios 2008?

Comment: What do you mean by "not what I imagined"? Slightly inaccurate result? Grossly incorrect result? Compilation error? Run-time bug? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Rizier123 Well if i put 0 and 10 (or anything for n) i should be getting 0 also. But keep getting 1.

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-BrownYou say that this program has an "output error" Could you add your expected and actual results to the question?

Comment: So the result should be x every time ?

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown `scanf` returns number of succesful conversions. In your case both calls should return 1: `int r = scanf("%f", &x); if(r == 1) { success }`

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`), notably to run your program step by step. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Don't use floating point types as loopvariables or indices. (`i` and `n` should be integer types)

Comment: @Rizier123 For 5 and 5 i get -3207.852295.  This is clearly wrong

Comment: why do you use i as float here?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Becuase if I put as int, i have to float the equation which I'm not sure how. Doing this meant i didnt have to write float for the equations.

Comment: What's "to float the equation"? In your program only the division can have wrong result if using the wrong type. A simple cast like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976011/how-to-get-fractions-in-an-integer-division) will solve that

Answer (score 3):

The expansion should have (-1)<sup>i</sup> in the numerator. And you should use an `int i`  as it is a loop variable and would go against conventions otherwise.

```
a = a + (pow(-1,i) * pow(x, (2 * i) + 1)) / f; /* Expansion sum */
```

or `replace pow(-1, i)` with `(i & 1 ? -1 : 1)`  where `i` is an `int`.

Comment: it should be (-1)^i. Power has higher precedence than negation

Comment: Thanks for the help. Forgot to do that.

Comment: note `i` is a floating point type. Not very useful for loop index or modulo operation / bitfidlling.

Comment: @rpattiso you can't use `-(i & 1)`. I forgot that it return 1 and 0 instead of -1

Comment: @joop Thanks, I never second guess assuming `i` is an `int`.

Comment: It's scary to use `^` to mean exponentiation when talking about C code, where (of course) `^` means something completely different. You can use `<sup>` in SO's markdown.

Comment: @unwind sorry for that. My notation is less of an issue for me at this time as I'm more used to general maths. I'll learn though

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown I wasn't commenting to you, but to @rpattiso (who wrote this answer). I see that you used the `^` notation in your question, too. You can edit and fix that. :)

Comment: @unwind Thanks, I'll look into SO's markdown, maybe there are lots of gems there.

Comment: @unwind what would be more appropriate then?

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown Have a look now. :)

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown `(-1)<sup>i</sup>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    float x, a, f;
    int i, n, sign;

    printf("Value for x: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("Value for n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=1, f=1.0, a=x, sign=-1; i<=n; i++){
        f *= (2*i+1)*2*i;
        a += sign * pow(x, 2.0*i+1) / f;
        sign *= -1;
    }

    printf("Answer is %f.\n", a); /*Taylor expansion completed*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does 'sign' mean?

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown `-1` or `1`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I haven't a clue what '+=' and '*=' does.

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown E.g `a+=b` meant `a = a + b`, also `a*=b` meant `a = a * b`

Comment: For 'f *= (2*i+1)*2*i' why can't it just be 'f *= (2*i+1)'

Comment: Might be worth keeping `float f` as factorials grow outside the `int` range pretty quickly.

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown for n > 1, (2n+1)! = (2n+1) * 2n * (2(n-1)+1)!, and (2(n-1)+1)! is the previous value in f.

Comment: So if i wanted to replicate with cos(x), I'd do 'f*=(2*i)*(2*i-1)' right?

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown (2k+1)! = (2k+1) * (2k) * (2(k-1)+1)!, `f*=2*i*(2*i+1);`

Comment: @rpattiso _float f as factorials grow outside the int_ yes, but The accuracy of float seems to be enough in small n. `f` has returned. ;)

Comment: It would be helpful to include some text along with the code.

Comment: it's a simple code of the Taylor expansion. Also that's part of the OP is wrong.